# How to obtain optimal basis matrix B for LP in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am solving a standard LP problem:

```
min C'*x
S.t. A*x=b;x>=0;
```

After obtaining the solution through `linprog`, I want to obtain the optimal basis B corresponding to that solution. Simplex codes other than provided by MATLAB are very slow for the large-scale problems.

My problem has degeneracy.

Comment: Solvers like Cplex, Gurobi, Xpress or Mosek slower than Matlabs linprog on large problems? That would be really surprising. Anyway, almost any LP solver will return basis status arrays.

Comment: I was talking about the simplex codes done in MATLAB. I guess CPLEX does not return the basis index array. If it does, how can I obtain that?

Comment: Yes it does. Please consult the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal basis of a non-degenerate LP is given by lambda = 0, where, lambda is the Lagrangian multipliers. Within MATLAB, lambda is available as the final output, i.e.

`[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = linprog(___)`

So to find the basis, simply type `k = find(lambda == 0)`.

However, the value of zero is problematic from a numerical perspective (almost nothing is ever completely 0 in floating-point arithmetic), so you might want to settle for something like `k = find(lambda <= 1e-5)`. However, again, depending on the problem (and how well-behaved it is), this might not be correct either.

So, what can you do? There are basically two ways around this:

- Use a commercial solver: commercial solvers tend to be much better in the accuracy of the Lagragian multipliers, especially for badly defined problems. Try Gurobi or CPLEX, and if you are a University student they are for free anyways. They have a similar way of getting lambda out, but are much more reliable in my experience.
- Use the constraint values: you basically do `k = find(x > 1e-5)`, and look what it gives you as results. This suffers from the same setbacks as using the Lagrangian, but it might help.

However, you then still need to deal with primal and dual degeneracy, if it occurs. Not to dive in too much, but basically you need to always check that you have exactly `n` active constraints (`n` being the number of optimization variables). If you have more or less than that, you have a problem, and you need to put an appropriate check into your code for that.

Comment: Actually, my problem does degenerate. I tried the Meggido's Algorithm to obtain the basis but it takes too much time, due to my programming style I guess, even for a 1000x1000 problem.  Does any solver provide the optimal basis?

Comment: Use Gurobi or CPLEX, and then try. Check for non-zero variables in the solution.

Comment: I have tried the CPLEX but, the number of zero `lambda` values is less than the number of variables.

Comment: Then you need to revisit your problem formulation. Either you have numerical issues (scaling, near-zero stuff etc.) or some structural degeneracy that you have to analyze appropriately. One common way is to do sensitivity analysis (i.e. vary your coefficients b and c slightly), and see what solution comes out.